# Connecting to phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm helping a non-profit organization with a large website they run. Their current host/developer hasn't responded to them in over a year. They want to get their files and database and move to a new host.

When I load the phpMyAdmin page and try to log in, it returns the following error.

```
#2000 - (mysqlnd_ms) Exclusive usage of configuration enforced but did not find the correct INI file section
```

What could be causing this? Is there a problem with the php.ini configuration?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you bypass this by using a shell login and mysqldump  ?  phpMyAdmin can choke on large exports anyway.

Comment: It's possible. let me try. not the best with SSH.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump recipe:

SSH in using the website user (or root and then su to website user)

cd to the public_html or httpdocs folder `cd httpdocs`

`mysqldump -cuUSER_NAME -p DATABASE_NAME -eqQc > filename.sql`

(USER_NAME is MySQL connection user name, if you don't have it and DATABASE_NAME try downloading all the script files for the site and looking through them for MySQL code.)

Optional : `gzip -9 filename.sql`

Download filename.sql or .gz with your FTP program.  7-zip can extract from .gz files.